# GitZilla's update hook error?

Tags: git, gitzilla, pybugz

Trying to integrate Bugzilla with GIT using GITZILLA.

Versions using are :
Git version : 1.8.2.1
gitzilla==2.0
pybugz==0.10

However, while doing the push , update hook throwing below error :

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 266 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "hooks/update", line 8, in <module>
remote:     load_entry_point('gitzilla==2.0', 'console_scripts', 'gitzilla-update')()
remote:   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/gitzilla/hookscripts.py", line 190, in update
remote:   File "/opt/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 324, in readfp
remote:     self._read(fp, filename)
remote:   File "/opt/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
remote:     raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
remote: ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
remote: file: /etc/gitzillarc, line: 140
remote: ' [/opt/gitrepo/newtest/.git]\n'
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To shivpal.chawla@10.86.41.14:/opt/gitrepo/newtest
! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'shivpal.chawla@10.86.41.14:/opt/gitrepo/newtest'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error trace it says:

> file: /etc/gitzillarc, line: 140
>   ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section
>   headers

So it's a problem with your gitzillarc file at line 140, you might want to check it for any error.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response. I already checked this line in gitzillarc file and found no leading spaces at all corresponding to line 140. Can you advice what else can this error be related to?

Comment: can you put gitzillarc in a gist or a pastebin?

Comment: uploaded /etc/gitzillarc file in pastebin. Kindly check and revert here. Thx.

Comment: what's the link to pastebin file?

Comment: Getting this error now. earlier one is fixed now.             remote: Traceback (most recent call last): remote: File "hooks/post-receive", line 8, in <module> remote: load_entry_point('gitzilla==2.0', 'console_scripts', 'gitzilla-post-receive')() remote: File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/gitzilla/hookscripts.py", line 176, in post_receive remote: File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/gitzilla/hooks.py", line 80, in post_receive remote: File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/gitzilla/hookscripts.py", line 125, in bz_init remote: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Bugz' .

Comment: Yes, it's a different issue now. Would you mind creating another question? It's better to have one problem at a time